# SQL ignores whitespaces?

Tags: mysql

I came across something very interesting. MySQL ignores whitespaces in `varchar` and `char`.

So if you insert this `'a '` and `'a'`
You will have 2 records both containing `'a'`

Also for `select
Where col='a '`
Will return both inserted rows

If you make `col1` unique, inserting `'a'` and `'a '` will throw an error.

This will probably make a lot of systems vulnerable taking into consideration that insert also truncates the data if the length of the inserting string exceeds the length of `varchar`, i.e., `col1` has `varchar(5)`, inserting `'12345'` and `'123456'` will result in having 2 records saying `'12345'`.

So if for example you try to make an account using the admin's email `'a@a.b'` and use `'a@a.b  thiswilbetruncuateddeutovarcharlength'`, Then technically you have an account with the same email as as the admin, (this example was a recent IPBoard exploit which can be found here: http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/25441/ )

So did I get this all right? and can somebody provide some more background on this since I wasnt able to find mch online :(

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the columns are defined as VARCHAR or CHAR? It sounds like you are using an INT column and simply sending quoted input to it.

Comment: Study this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/char.html there is a detailed description of char/varchar behaviour in MySql there.

Comment: @EdCottrell , Yes I'm sure :)